# What's the correct etymology of Benin?

Tags: etymology, african-languages

From [etymonline](https://www.etymonline.com/word/benin#:%7E:text=former%20West%20African%20kingdom%2C%20from,the%20former%20nation%20of%20Dahomey.):

> former West African kingdom, from the Bini people, whose name is perhaps related to Arabic bani "sons."

From Wikipedia article for [Edo people](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Edo_people#:%7E:text=%22Ubini%22%2C%20a%20Edo%20word,from%20the%20River%20Niger%20Area.):

> The name "Benin" (and "Bini") is a Portuguese corruption, ultimately from the word "Ubini", which came into use during the reign of Oba (ruler) Ewuare, c. 1440. "Ubini", a Edo word meaning Livable , used by Pa Idu, the progenitor of the Edo people to describe the area found as a Livable Locale, during their sojourn from the River Niger Area. Ubini was later corrupted to Benin by the mixed ethnicities living together at the centre; and further corrupted to Benin around 1485, when the Portuguese began trade relations with Oba Ewuare giving them coral beads.

The Wikipedia entry has a source (Vanguardngr.com) but I can't open it.

**Update**: I opened that [source](https://www.vanguardngr.com/2019/10/yoruba-leaders-disagree-over-origin-meaning-of-their-name/):

> Bini is said to be a name given by Oranmiyan which is said, literally, to mean anger.

Which etymology is true?

Comment: Dear close-voter, Can you please tell me why this question should close?

Comment: Contextless etymology question:
Languages are always changing; words change their meanings and are borrowed between languages unpredictably. So questions asking for the origin of words or phrases are off-topic unless they demonstrate that there is a reasonable assumption of systematicity, by situating themselves within a historical context of language change or contact.